# CSS problems with floating, one style sheet, same id's

Tags: css, css-float

I am currently working on a project in which the navigation bar is floated to the left and then the content is on the right of that, also floated so it is flush up against the navigation content. I currently have the first page fine and floats perfectly, but when I try to float the next page's content, it jumps down and will not float at all. Both are in separate div's and on separate html documents and both have same float attributes. I do not understand why if both have the same exact code and have enough room for floating, why can't the second page's content do the same?? I am and must use one stylesheet for all pages.

CSS for body

```
body {
        width: 980px;
    margin-left: 8%;
    margin-right: 8%;
    margin-top:2%;  
    padding: 0;
    font-family: "gill sans", sans-serif;
    font-size: .8 em;
    background-color: #CCC;
}
```

CSS for navigation

```
#containernav {
float: left;
padding: 0;
width: 120px;}
```

CSS for page 1 and 2

```
#content_main, #content_main2 {
padding:0;
margin:0;
width:750px;
float:left;
background-color:#A30000; }
```

Comment: An example would be nice. My first guess is 'not enough space' (despite what you say).

Comment: Yes, adding to what @Nikita said, please also mention the browser you're using.

Comment: If you could provide the CSS for the elements *containing* the floated elements, that would be helpful. Float depends on properties in the parent element, which may be causing your troubles.

Comment: How would I show an example? sorry I am new to this website. I am using firefox to test all of this. my page has a width of 980px so I don't think space is a problem, especially since the first page floats fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess would be the content inside the floated div on page 2 is larger then 750px, thus causing its parent to stretch, and the div to be pushed down.

Comment: Got it! Thank you! Was messing with the div's and inside found one that was too large and I was not using... too many div's... Thanks again!